How to turn Koka effect control flow into an external iterator?
Koka has nice ways to model control flow with ctl effects:
pub fun main()
    var n := 20
    var sum := 0
    (handler {
        ctl yield(j) {
            println(j)
            sum := sum + j
            n := n - 1
            if n > 0
            then resume(())
        }
    }){
        fibonacci()
    }
    println("sum=" ++ sum.show)

effect yield
    ctl yield(i: int): ()

fun fibonacci() : <div,yield> ()
    var i := 0
    var j := 1
    yield(j)
    while { True }
        val k = i + j
        i := j
        j := k
        yield(j)

(I'm sure this is not good Koka code but hopefully the question is still answerable)
What I want to achieve is to create an interator that can be polled to the next number. Something like:
fun next(iter: iterator): <console> maybe<int> 

Essentially to invert the control flow and poll values, so I can do other logic without putting it in the effect handler.
